# Составление паттернов

Tags: java

Нужно вырезать некий блок символов из строки
блок вот такой

```
ParName{
//content
}
```

Мне нужно вырезать и ParName и { и content и }
Я использую

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?\\{+\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(out);
f(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group().subSequence(0, m.group().length()));
}else{
    System.err.println("Ошибка");
}
```

Выводит Ошибка, -не нашел?

Comment: Вероятно, вы пропустили точку перед плюсом. В данной интерпретации вы ожидаете множество фигурных скобок.

Comment: Не помогло...((

Comment: При чем при паттерне ".*?\\{" он выводит ParName{

Comment: У вас два квантификатоа подряд * - любое кол-во совпадений, сразу следом у вас ? - ноль или одно совпадение
Что вы хотиете сопопставить этой .*? частью регэкспа?

Comment: Ну я думал,что это отловит ParName

Comment: Получается,мне надо использовать .*\{.*\} ?

Comment: Я пришел к такому: "^.*\{(.*\n)*\}" но он выводит все,что совпадает такому шаблону.Можно их,скажем,раскидать по массиву?

Comment: @АлександрПоташев, тут ? - это переключатель режима жадности, не?

Comment: @vp_arth,эт как?

Comment: @AseTry, теперь выделяйте необходимые части круглыми скобками. Про жадность: если `.*` - жадный, то `.*?` - ленивый(и наоборот, зависит от флагов), первый захватит максимально возможное число символов удовлетворяющее выражению, второй минимально возможное.

Comment: Есть ещё супержадные и ревнивые квантификаторы - но это совсем другая история)

Comment: Угу,теперь я ситуация чуть прояснилась,спасибо.

Comment: @vp_arth каюсь, был неправ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярные выражения интересная вещь. Когда кажется, что уже предусмотрел всё, что нужно, возникает еще пятнадцать идей, как усовершенствовать свою регулярку и написать более однозначно :).

Предлагаю такой вариант регулярки для решения задачи:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?ms)(?:ParName\\{){1}(.*[^}].*){0,1}[}]{1}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ParName{ my \ninternal\n \t\ttext }");
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("result: " + m.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("not found ...");
}
```

Полезно посмотреть:

1. Исходники класса Pattern.
2. [Документация Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
3. Пример использования: [match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression)
4. [java-regex-tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

П.С.
Еще пример регулярного выражения от активного участника `"(?ms)(?:ParName\\{)([^}]*)\\}"`

Comment: `.{0,1}` - это аналог `.?`, а вот `.{1}` - это аналог `.+` или `.`? Сразу и не припомню... Зачем? Да и всё остальное очень странно. Требование одной не фигурной_скобки посреди множества любых символов? Класс символов из одного символа- чтобы не экранировать? Почему тогда в другом месте экран? Про `(?ms)` я вообще боюсь спрашивать, может  я чего не знаю в контексте java?

Comment: Кончено,спасибо,но я уже решил проблему банальным String Objects[] = out.split("}"); xD

Comment: @AseTry, лучше запишите ваше решение со Split в виде ответа. Скорее всего, это наиболее адекватное решение вашей задачи)

Comment: @vp_arth, спасибо за хорошие вопросы, но их очень много. Все ответы можно найти по ссылкам в моем ответе. Если что-то не найдете, то создайте отдельный вопрос - отвечу.

Comment: Товарищ, это не вопросы, это критика.

Comment: уважаемый @vp_arth, если есть что-то по существу, то создайте чат на мете, обсудим.

Comment: Что тут обсуждать-то? Просто ваша регулярка слишком кучерявая по сравнению, скажем, с идентичной `"(?ms)(?:ParName\\{)([^}]*)\\}"`. Ну и флаги в `Pattern.compile` лучше передавать вторым параметром.

Comment: @vp_arth, не спорю про идеальность моего решения. Регулярки -
 вещь философская и идеала здесь не существует. Просто сразу надо было предложить более оптимальный вариант, а не спамить кучу бессмысленных комментов.

Answer (score 2):

Спустя некоторое время,я наткнулся на более простое решение этой проблемы.
оно заключается в использовании split

```
String Objects[] = out.split("}\n");
int b = 0;
while(Objects.length > b){
System.out.println("Obj-"+b+": "+Objects[b] + "}");
b++;
}
```

Вывод будет следующий:

```
Obj-0: Object1{
##########content###########
}
Obj-1: Object2{
##########content###########
}
```

Может подойти,как вариант для аналогичных целей.

Comment: Если split() будет достаточно для решения задачи, то согласен, лучше его использовать. split() будет работать быстрее, чем регулярные выражения.